# R For Loop Write CSV with List of Dataframes and Path Names

Tags: r, for-loop, export-to-csv

I am trying to write a for loop in R with  a list of dataframes and path names For some reason,the second dataframe is the only one that exports. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
df1 <- data.frame(num = sample(1:10, 6, replace = TRUE), letter = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 6, replace = 
TRUE))
df2 <- data.frame(num = sample(150:160, 6, replace = TRUE), letter = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 6, replace 
= TRUE))

list_dfs <- list(df1,df2)

paths <- c("C:\\Export\\file1.csv","C:\\Export\\file2.csv")

for (i in 1:length(list_dfs)) {
   for (f in 1:length(paths)) {
    write.csv(list_dfs[i], file = paths[f], row.names = FALSE)
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me that you export `df1` correctly, in the first outer loop and then overwrite the same files in the second outer loop. You need to distinguish the file names.

What exactly is your intention? Your code looks like you want to export every data frame twice. If you want to do it only once, you can drop the inner loop and write `paths[i]`instead of `paths[f]`.

Comment: I suggest: Remove the inner loop and replace `file = paths[f]` with `file = paths[i]`. And replace `list_dfs[i]` with `list_dfs[[i]]`.

Comment: That got me exactly what I needed, thank you both! Removed the inner loop. Replaced list_dfs[i] with list_dfs[[i]], replaced file = path[f] with file = paths[i].

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
for (i in 1:length(list_dfs)) {
  write.csv(list_dfs[i], file = paths[i], row.names = FALSE)
  }
}
```

The code you provided was writing `list_dfs[1]` to `path[1]` and then `path[2]`. Followed by `list_dfs[2]` to `path[1]` and then `path[2]`, resulting in `list_dfs[2]` being written to `path[1]` and `path[2]`.

If you want to include a check that `list_dfs` and `paths` are the same length you could do:

```
for (i in 1:length(list_dfs)) {
  if(length(list_dfs) != length(path)){stop("mismatch in number of data frames and paths")}
  write.csv(list_dfs[i], file = paths[i], row.names = FALSE)
  }
}
```

Ultimately though, if you want to export each data frame once, you only need one `for()` loop.

I hope this helps!